# How to get retiring and new additions in lines from two files?

Tags: shell, batch-file, awk, diff

**Problem :**

I have 2 files which will be updated daily based on some online feed, files contains likes with input and daily some new lines will be added and some will be deleted. Also daily the order of lines in files will change.So I want to extract the lines which are added today and also want to know how many are deleted form yesterday?

**Approach I followed :**

Suppose say 3 files `2017-07-17.txt , 2017-07-18.txt and 2017-07-19.txt` files with data as below.

**2017-07-17.txt**

```
a
b
c
```

**2017-07-18.txt**

```
a
b
d
e
f
```

**2017-07-19.txt**

```
f
e
a
c
b
d
g
```

Did diff on first two files.

```
3d2
< c
4a4,5
> e
> f
```

From the output it is easy to extract the data and know what is deleted and what is added. But My input ranges from 100k to 200k lines of data daily so using `diff` is not working.

problem I faced during this approach

When someday say `2017-07-19.txt` the input changed its order, `diff` logic works very wiredly as it scans line to line.

```
$ diff 2017-07-18.txt 2017-07-19.txt
0a1,2
> f
> e
1a4
> c
4,5c7
< e
< f
---
> g
```

Is there any solution which I can use to get output like this.

**Expected Output:**

```
$ diff 2017-07-18.txt 2017-07-19.txt
    Addeed : c
             g

    Deleted : None
```

Comment: What does it have to do with python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat awk-script
NR==FNR{a[$0];next} 
{ 
  if($0 in a)
    a[$0]=1
  else
    add=add"\t"$0"\n"
} 
END {
  for(i in a)
    if(a[i]!=1)
      del=del"\t"i"\n"
  printf "Added:%s\n",(add)?add:"None\n"
  printf "Deleted:%s",(del)?del:"None\n"
}

$ awk -f awk-script 2017-07-18.txt 2017-07-19.txt
Added:  c
        g

Deleted:None
```

Comment: Pretty nice with `None` and all. ^

Comment: Thanks @JamesBrown

Comment: i agree (i copy it in my solution for a nice presentation)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. But note this solution will cause you to read your entire files in memory.

```
f1 = open("2017-07-18.txt")
f2 = open("2017-07-19.txt")

lines1 = set(f1.readlines())
lines2 = set(f2.readlines())

print lines2 - lines1 # added today

print lines1 - (lines2 & lines1) # deleted today
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next }              # hash first file contents to a
{
    if($1 in a)                     # if second file item is found in a
        delete a[$1]                # delete it
    else b[$1]                      # otherwise add it to b hash
}
END {                               # in the end
    print "Added:"
    for(i in b)                     # added are in b
        print i
    print "Deleted:"
    for(i in a)                     # deleted are in a
    print i
}' 2017-07-18.txt 2017-07-19.txt    # mind the order
Added:
c
g
Deleted:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
findstr /v /x /L /g:filename1 filename2 |find /c /v ""
```

*may* yield a count of differences between the two files (not sure that 200k lines will blow any limit)

Find the lines in filename2 that `/v` do not `/x` exactly match `/L` literally `/g:` the lines in this file. Output the result to `find` which will then `/c` count the lines from the previous command that `/v` don't match `""` (ie. count the lines from the previous command)

To assign this to a variable, use

```
for /f %%a in ('findstr /v /x /L /g:filename1 filename2 ^|find /c /v "" ') do set count=%%a
```

(Note the quotes and the caret inserted before the pipe)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
   # add and remove depending in wich file
   { A[$1] += (FNR==NR) * 2 - 1 } 

   END {
      # set in different category depending of count + create human list
      for( a in A){ T[A[a]] = T[A[a]] "\n  " a }

      # display result (thanks to @CWLiu very nice code)
      printf "Added: %s\n", (T[1]) ? T[1] : "None"
      printf "Deleted: %s\n", (T[-1]) ? T[-1] : "None"
      }
   ' 2017-07-19.txt 2017-07-18.txt
```

for gaining a bite memory consumption, we could delete the A[x] element when it reach 0 in first part or at least discard in the for loop in END section